# spatie/laravel-backup "mysqldump" doesn't recognized when I run it through Artisan class

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backup

I'm using [spatie/laravel-backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup) in a WAMP localhost.

It works fine when I type manually in the windows cmd:

```
php artisan backup:run
```

But when I try to run the backup using the laravel Artisan class:

```
Artisan::call('backup:run');
```

It throw an error:

```
'mysqldump' not recognized ...
```

In the laravel mysql config I've also specified the path to the dumper:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            // ...
            'dump' => [
                'dump_binary_path' => 'E:/wamp/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.9/bin',
           ],
        ],
```

How can i fix that?

---

**EDIT**

Probably it's just support "bug" for windows (finded out thanks Loek's answer), [as the author says](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/issues/311), so can I run a backup in a controller without a command safely? maybe with something like:

```
use Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJobFactory;

BackupJobFactory::createFromArray(config('laravel-backup'))->run();
```

As the [command](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/blob/master/src/Commands/BackupCommand.php) itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's the forward slashes. Try this:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        // ...
        'dump' => [
            'dump_binary_path' => 'E:\\wamp\\wamp64\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.7.9\\bin',
       ],
    ],
```

**EDIT**

Support for Windows is wonky at best, with multiple "This package doesn't support Windows" comments from the creators on GitHub issues. This one is the latest: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/issues/311

It could also be a permission problem. Executing from the command line is probably happening from another user than executing from the web server, so Windows is denying access to mysqldump.

**2nd edit**

As long as you make sure the controller only gets called when it needs to be, I don't see why this wouldn't work!

Comment: Doesn't works, I've also already tried 'E:/wamp/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.9/bin' and 'E:\wamp\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\bin'

Comment: Even with the double backward slashes? And I don't know if it's a typo, but there is a forward slash in your second path

Comment: What is the version of your package? The issues on GitHub mention this problem on windows and they should have been solved from version 2.0.1: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/issues/265 .

Comment: I've the latest version, composer.json: "spatie/laravel-backup": "^4.3"

Comment: See my edit. I guess it's because of windows (the package's requirements even state this), but I wonder why it runs from the command line

Comment: And my 2nd edit, I don't see amy reason why it wouldn't be unsafe as long as you lock the controller down properly